# is there a way to merge these 2 kotlin functions?

Tags: java, kotlin

```kotlin
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity

fun <T> responseEntity(block: (ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder) -> T): ResponseEntity<T> {
  val builder = ResponseEntity.ok()
  return builder.body(block(builder))
}

fun responseEntityVoid(block: (ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder) -> Unit): ResponseEntity<Void> {
  return ResponseEntity.ok().also(block).body(null)
}
```

if I pass the `block` param with type `() -> Unit` to the first function, it returns `ResponseEntity<Unit>`, but not `ResponseEntity<Void>`(which is defined in java interface)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible because `T` has to be inferred from the return type of the lambda.

Maybe making it an overload with the same function name achieves what you're trying to do? It requires a third function to be able to resolve the types. `@JvmName` is necessary to avoid overload ambiguity.

I don't use Spring and didn't test this. It's a bit hacky with the types. In `responseEntityImpl`, it converts Unit lambda result to null so `body()` returns what should be a `ResponseEntity<Void>`, but the compiler thinks of it as `ResponseEntity<Unit>`. The public function casts it to `ResponseEntity<Void>`.

```
private fun <T: Any> responseEntityImpl(block: (ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder) -> T): ResponseEntity<T> {
    val builder = ResponseEntity.ok()
    return builder.body(block(builder).takeIf { it != Unit })
}

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
@JvmName("responseEntityVoid")
fun responseEntity(block: (ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder) -> Unit): ResponseEntity<Void> {
    return responseEntityImpl(block) as ResponseEntity<Void>
}

fun <T: Any> responseEntity(block: (ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder) -> T): ResponseEntity<T> {
    return responseEntityImpl(block)
}
```